# Is this possible to set up in the dns register other than the web hosting?

Tags: redirects, dns, subdomain, cloudflare

My domain is hosted in a domain name registry cloudflare and the website is hosted in the shopify. We have QR code tagged with each product selling in the shopify. If a customer scan it it will go to mydomain.com?specialCode=123456 and he/she could win a prize. Recently we've developed the sns application on different sub domain sns.mydomain.com. I want to know if we can set up redirect to go to sns.mydomain.com if the url has specialCode attached. Hopefully I can set up a redirect on the name on the cloudflare so we don't need to redirect from client side since shopify doesn't give you access to the server side. Is this possible?

Example
mydomain.com?specialCode=123456  => sns.mydomain.com/specialcode=1234

Comment: Your question is unclear to me.  You cant do this in DNS, it has to be done on the web server.

Comment: You don't say where your DNS is hosted.  Your DNS registrar, your DNS host, your main site web host, and your subdomain web host could all be separate, but you'll need to tell us more about how it is all set up if you want better help.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I'm pretty sure the website is on Shopify and is integrated with Cloudflare. If this is correct, the solution in my answer works as page rules are supported.

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/203464660-Using-Cloudflare-with-Shopify

Comment: Maybe.  They only say they are using Cloudflare registrar.  They didn't say they are using Cloudflare as CDN.  They need to clarify.   @MikeCiffone, your answer is really just a stab in the dark.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller 100% shot in the dark.

Comment: The domain name is registered @cloudflare and website is hosted in shopify. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @ShinyaKoizumi I'm glad that my guess was correct. If you wouldn't mind editing your question to better describe the circumstances (Domain on Cloudflare, hosted on Shopify then Stephen maybe will re-open it so that others may comment or provide additional insight.

Comment: IT's all there from the beginning. Maybe "the domain is hosted in shopify" part was so clear, but domain name is registered with Cloudflare and the shopify is mentioned so I am not sure why this is flagged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Cloudflare Page Rules

You can accomplish this using the Page Rules feature. Here is a [getting started tutorial by Cloudflare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/218411427).

What you want to do is map `example.com/?parameter1=value1` to `subdomain.example.com`. The problem is matching the query parameters.

Best route I think is to add a dedicated directory for prizes and use a wildcard. You would just have to create a separate QR code for winners.

```
mydomain.com/special-prize/* -> sns.mydomain.com/you-lost
mydomain.com/special-prize/w/* -> sns.mydomain.com/you-won
```

Please be advised wildcards will forward *anything after* `/special-prices/` and `/special-prices/w/`.

Here's what the Page Rules section looks like:

[image]

---

Checking the prize code in a programmatic way...I think *can* be done using **Query String Sort** and you'd need to have an enterprise account. It's designed as a method to control caching so this would be an unorthodox usage to say the least.

You can learn more about that [here](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/206776797-Understanding-Query-String-Sort). You would set up the page rule the same as before just with your winning string in it. I would open a ticket with their technical support.

---

Without Shopify and CF it would be very simple on a typical server. In Nginx, of the top of my head something like:

```
location / {
    if ($arg_specialCode = true) {
        return 301 https://sns.mydomain.com$uri$is_args$args;
    }
}
```

`$is_args` is an empty string if there are no arguments, or a `?` indicating the start of the query string.

Then `$args` adds the arguments

`$query_string` can be used as well, same methodology.